# Sas : viewer results are the same as output

Tags: html, sas, tabulate

I am writting because I have a problem with my results viewer on Sas 9.4.

When they charge the resukts are the same as in output. Instead of having a table with cell I have a table draw with -+|. Layouts options does not work and when exporting to excel for example each line are contain into one cell (with | where it shiuld change cell).
Is there sonething I can do?
Because like this I am loosing a lot of the options SAS offer

(I already checked tools:options:preferences:results and checked create html)

Thank you on advanced for your help!

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what the problem is, unfortunately.  If I understand, you're trying to get HTML results out of SAS by default instead of the Listing results, correct, but you only see Listing (the "ascii art" tables)?  This happens even if you start a new SAS session, with the results->create html option turned on?  This is in Windows, right?

Comment: What happens if you run something like `ods listing close; ods html; proc print data=sashelp.class; run; ods html close;` - does that show you html?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the results viewer is working, but the results display are looking the same as if it was in output (with a drawn table with |+-) and not as a table. Thus when exporting it is read as if it were text and does not take the cells into account (cannot use it in excel or so on). Plus if I want to change layout (color or something else) it does not work (as output is unaffected by those changes). Is it clearer this way?

Comment: Code please.  If your code is using a data step to create a text report it will require re-writing to produce a tabular HTML/Excel report instead.

Comment: Please show the code you're running, screenshots of your output that isn't in the format you want.

Comment: Code ia simple proc tabulate:

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you'd put results in Excel.
I'm guessing you're copying from HTML to Excel?

```
ods excel file = '/home/fkhurshed/Demo/demo.xlsx';

proc means data=sashelp.class;
run;

proc freq data=sashelp.class;
table sex*gender / norow nocol nopercent;
run;

ods excel close;
```